# pytest: passing list as arguments from command line is not working

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I am facing below error when i run pytest with list as arguments from command line..

pytest -vs test_sample.py --html=results.html --A_list=[A1, A2, A3]

**ERROR: file not found: A2,**

below is my **test_sample.py** code

```
import pytest

def test_functionality(A_list):
    print("element in list: {}".format(A_list))
```

Below is my **conftest.py** code

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--A_list", action="store", default="default name")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    option_value = metafunc.config.option.A_list
    if 'A_list' in metafunc.fixturenames and option_value is not None:
        metafunc.parametrize("A_list", [option_value])
```

This is working fine if i pass only one element like below

pytest -vs test_sample.py --html=results.html **--A_list=A1**

**But it is getting failed if i run pytest with list of elements for A_list like below**

```
    pytest -vs test_sample.py --html=results.html --A_list=[A1, A2, A3]
```

Can anyone let me know how to pass list as pytest arguments from command line ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to pass a Python list as a command line argument. This does not work - command line arguments are just strings that need to be parsed. Especially you cannot have spaces in the option if you don't surround it with apostrophes.

What you could do is to pass the list as a string, for example by comma separating the entries:

```
pytest -vs test_sample.py --html=results.html --A_list="A1,A2,A3"
```

Note that the apostrophes are strictly not needed here as you don't have spaces, but you can use them anyway. Then you can parse the string into a list:

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    option_value = metafunc.config.option.A_list
    if option_value:
        params = option_value.split(",")
        if 'A_list' in metafunc.fixturenames:
            metafunc.parametrize("A_list", params)
```

Comment: Thanks @MrBean Bremen for your answer ..

I have posted similar question for multiple fixtures in another thread , it would be good if i can get solution for the same. Especially how conftest.py should look  .


Here is the link for the same.
[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864930/how-to-pass-multiple-list-arguments-by-command-line-to-multiple-pytest-fixtures)

Comment: Ok, will have a look later. Does this one not work for you?

Comment: Thanks . Its working for me ... 

Actually i am using 4 fixtures in my code, so i need to pass list as argument from command line for all the fixtures.  I have mentioned the same in the above link, you can look into it once you get time

Comment: Thanks. I have now accepted your answer .....I thought i had accepted your Answer and it is not displaying here as my reputation is less than 15 ..