# Passing pytest fixture in parametrize

Tags: python, parameter-passing, pytest, fixtures

I'm getting following error by passing my fixture defined in conftest.py in @pytest.mark.parametrize:

```
pytest --alist="0220,0221" test_1.py -v -s
NameError: name 'alist' is not defined
```

**conftest.py:**

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--alist", action="store")

@pytest.fixture
def alist(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--alist").split(",")
```

**test_1.py:**

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("channel", alist, scope="class")
class TestRaIntegrationReplay:

    def test_ra_start_time(self, channel):
        print(channel)
```

If I am passing alist to the test as fixture like:

```
    def test_ra_start_time(self, alist):
        for channel in alist:
            print(channel)
```

It works well, but it does not work with passing to @pytest.mark.parametrize

Comment: I have answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63622139/12480730) some time ago, should work for your case too, e.g. do the parametrization in `pytest_generate_tests`, as you cannot pass a fixture to `mark.parametrize` directly.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thanks, I managed to apply your first solution with modifying "pytest_generate_tests" hook in conftest.py and it worked, but I have another question now: is there a way to apply alist fixture to all tests in the class to avoid passing "alist" fixture to every test?

Or there is a way to modify pytest_generate_tests to apply hook in case of fixture alist applied to the class?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you don't want to use the fixture genererally, or you just want to use it where needed? The second case is already covered by the `if "alist" in metafunc.fixturenames` part.

Comment: I'll put it in an answer to clarify with the risk of creating a duplicate... That will make it easier to discuss it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you cannot directly pass a fixture to a `mark.parametrize` decorator, because the decorator is evaluated at load time.
You can do the parametrization at run time instead by implementing `pytest_generate_tests`:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "alist" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        values = metafunc.config.option.alist
        if value is not None:
            metafunc.parametrize("alist", value.split(","))

def test_ra_start_time(alist):
    for channel in alist:
        print(channel)

def test_something_else():
    # will not be parametrized
    pass
```

The parametrization is done based on the presence of the `alist` parameter in the test function. For parametrization to work, this parameter is needed (otherwise you would get an error because of the missing argument).