# How to access fixture's values as input to parametrized test

Tags: python, pytest

In `py.test` I need to dynamically define tests, depending on tests I defined in a file.

So what I was thinking is to define a fixture in `conftest.py` that reads the file and returns a dictionary with the tests.

File `tests.json`:

```
{
    "test1": "text",
    "test2": "42",
    "test3": 1
}
```

I then define a fixture in `conftest.py` to return the dictionary with the tests:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--tests",
        default="tests.json",
    )

@pytest.fixture
def mytests(request):
    testfile = request.config.getoption("--tests")
    with open(testfile) as f:
        tests = json.load(f)
    return tests
```

and then I can use a parametrized test as follows in `test_pytest.py`:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_name", [(key) for key, value in mytests.items()])
def test1(test_name):
    print(test_name)
```

which does not work as, at this point, `py.test` does not seem to 'know' that `mytests` is a fixture. I get an error

```
E   NameError: name 'mytests' is not defined
```

How to handle this correctly? I just want to be able to either run all the test that are defined in the json file, or to be able to select a single test from it with the `-k` option if `py.test`.

How to do it?

---

Based on some comments given below I tried to implement something as follows:

```
@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "myparam" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        with open(metafunc.config.option.tests) as f:
            tests = json.load(f)

        # add parametrization for each fixture name
        for name, value in tests.items():
            print(name, value)
            metafunc.parametrize("mparam", (name, value))

def test1(myparam):
    print(myparam)
```

But with this I got an error

```
ERROR test_pytest.py - ValueError: duplicate 'myparam'
```

Comment: I don't see how your example is dynamic. It looks like you're intending to always statically run the same number of tests as there are elements in `tests.json`, a static number. (Why bother with a json file anyway? Store it as a python dict, in another file if you want, in the same number of lines.)

Comment: @Kache Can you answer my question or not?

Comment: You cannot use a fixture in `parametrize`, as it is called at load time. Just make it a normal function instead of a fixture and import it.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I am not sure I follow. You suggest to make the 'fixture' a normal function? That does not actually work, as the "function" `mytests` actually uses options for the filename. 

I will update the question to make it more and more clear

Comment: I see. You still cannot use the fixture in `parametrize`, but you could move the fixture code into `pytest_generate_test` and do the parametrization dynamically, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63622139/12480730).

Comment: I do not quite understand. In the `pytest_generate_test` function I seem to define some parameters, but the test function already knows it depends on the three values `a,b,c`. But these value could be different, depending on the tests defined in the json file. Not sure I understand. If you could provide a working example, that would be useful

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I have updated the question with something I tried but did not work

Comment: You almost got it - I added the correct way as an answer.

Comment: Looks like you found a solution that worked for you. Sorry if my suggestion wasn't clear, it was to use `@pytest.mark.parametrize` on "just a normal `dict`/`list`" of the testcases you otherwise have defined in the json file (or `json.loads()` it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot use a fixture in `mark.parametrize`. Fixtures can only be used in test functions and other fixtures.

To have dynamic parametrization like in this case, you can implement the hook function `pytest_generate_tests`:

```py
@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "test_name" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        testfile = metafunc.config.getoption("--tests")
        with open(testfile) as f:
            tests = json.load(f)
        metafunc.parametrize("test_name", tests.items())


def test1(test_name):
    print(test_name)
```

This will parametrize all tests with a "test_name" argument (e.g. fixture) with the items in the config file.

Running this with the given json file will result in something like:

```
$ python -m pytest -s
...
collected 3 items

test_pytest.py ('test1', 'text')
.('test2', '42')
.('test3', 1)
.
```